# C# PrincipalContext Error "Server names cannot contain a space character"

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the following error

'Server names cannot contain a space character' when using PrincipalContext to obtain information of a domain user.

This code works locally on my machine but craps out when I load it up on the Intranet web server.

```
            //GET CURRENT USER 
            String winUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            string[] domainUsername = winUser.Split(Convert.ToChar(@"\"));

            // set up domain context
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainUsername[0]);

            // find a user
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, domainUsername[1]);

            return user;
```

Answer (score 3):

for me it was because of below setting of PrincipalContext.

and it was resolved after changing idenity of Application pool from **ApplicationPoolIdenity** to **LocalSystem** .

it is not a real solution but may help somebody.

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext((Environment.UserDomainName == Environment.MachineName ?
            ContextType.Machine : ContextType.Domain), Environment.UserDomainName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because If there is no container  specified, the principal context class will create a System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry object by binding to builtin CN=Users container to start searching for users. System,

consider the example on this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2009/08/28/getting-an-exception-the-specified-directory-service-attribute-or-value-does-not-exist-when-you-try-to-search-a-user-in-an-ad-container-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-userprincipal-findbyidentity.aspx)  and about the exception [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2009/08/28/getting-an-exception-the-specified-directory-service-attribute-or-value-does-not-exist-when-you-try-to-search-a-user-in-an-ad-container-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-userprincipal-findbyidentity.aspx)  .

Comment: I tried specifying a container in this code :
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainUsername[0], "DC=com");

Again, it runs on my local machine, but not on the iis server

Comment: yes i tried specifying a container just like the example shown in the link you've given

Comment: The error indicates that you don’t specify the container. You can use the PrincipalContext(ContextType, String, String) method to initialize the instance

Comment: re-check datatype again